# how to work with custom wikibase using pywikibot

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikidata, pywikibot

I have my family file, user-config.py and user-password.py in the directory that i am running the following script from

```py
import os, sys
import pywikibot as pwb
pwb.config.register_families_folder(os.getcwd())
pwb.login.ClientLoginManager().login()
os.environ['PYWIKIBOT_DIR'] = os.getcwd()
site = pwb.Site()
repo = site.data_repository()
pg = pwb.ItemPage(repo, 'Q1')
pg.get()
```

But i get the following error

`AttributeError: DataSite instance has no attribute 'entity_sources'`

How do i resolve this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Pywikibot 8 [federated Wikibase](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T173195) was implemented. The [DataSite.get_repo_for_entity_type()](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.site.html#pywikibot.site._datasite.DataSite.get_repo_for_entity_type) method expects a `entity_sources()` method in your wikibase family file. To solve this issue with your data repository you can do the following:

**Pywikibot release 7.7.3 and below**

Since the extension federated Wikibase is not available here, a release downgrade could solve it but it is not recommended because Pywikibot 8 comes with a lot of improvements and bugfixes. See the [changelog](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/changelog.html) for more information.

**Pywikibot release 8.0 and 8.1**

All you have to do is to add the following lines into your wikibase family file:

```
def entity_sources(self, code: str) -> Dict[str, Tuple[str, str]]:
"""Provide repository site information for entity types."""
    return {}
```

For more information refer the [manual](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/family.html#family.WikibaseFamily.entity_sources).

**Pywikibot release 8.2**

If all entity types are handled by your wikibase repository given by your wikibase family file you can just inherit your family (maybe additionally) from [family.WikibaseFamily](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/family.html#family.WikibaseFamily). If you have different repositories for different entity types (i.e. federated Wikibase), you have to define your own `entity_sources` method in your wikibase family file like described in the *Pywikibot release 8.0 and 8.1* section.

**Hint**

For a federated Wikibase setting you can use [commons_family](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/api_ref/pywikibot.families.html#families.commons_family.Family.entity_sources) and [its code](https://doc.wikimedia.org/pywikibot/master/_modules/families/commons_family.html#Family.entity_sources) as a sample.

Comment: The explanations are IMHO far too technical. IMHO it would be helpful to explain the migration procedure for this (unfortunately breaking) change in more detail.